# How to implement google cloud print in windows mobile 8.1?

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-phone-8.1

Google cloud print android implementation available in https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android

Google cloud print c# implementation available in [Google Cloud Print using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846064/google-cloud-print-using-c-sharp)

The above methods does not work on windows phone 8.1. Please help.

Comment: Define "does not work".  It looks like a pretty run-of-the-mill web request, but the namespaces/classes for doing this are different for windows store apps so you'll need to do a bit of translating.

Comment: Describe in more detail how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you create a console application and get the code working on that app to verify that, yes the code, works as expected. The failure exhibited may be due to factors outside of the phone's code.

Once satisfied that one is getting the proper results, port the code over to Windows Phone.

---

Keep in mind that the `CLR` used by console applications is different from the `Silverlight` CLR so some methods may not be available. So one may have to find alternates to the missing or incorrect functions.